# Sage math plotting points in bigger sizes problem

Tags: plot, size, points, sage

How can plot a function with different point sizes?

```
f=[(k,k*sin(k^2)) for k in range(1,101)]
# size=[(i) for i in range(0,101)]

p=points(f, pointsize=5, color='red')
p.show()
```

How can I set different point sizes without using a list?

[image: Points plotting]